# Flutter - How to select any one item in ListView Builder during integration testing?

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, integration-testing

I'm testing my application using the "integration testing" method.

Currently, I'm testing the order history page. That page contains a list of containers wrapped with a gesture detector using the **ListView Builder widget**.

For testing, I set the condition to find the order history page. But I'm not sure how to give a condition to select one gesture detector.

For example, when testing the code it redirects to the order history page. That page has several containers. To redirect to the next page it has to click first or second or any one container. How to achieve this?

Doubt line:

```
await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key("OrderInfo")));

Or

await tester.tap(find.byType(GestureDetector));
```

Full test code:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';
import 'package:toyzania_app/main.dart' as app;

void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  group('end-to-end test', () {

 testWidgets('verify settings screen',
        (tester) async {
      app.main();

      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
      await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key('settingspage')));

      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
      expect(find.byType(OrderHistory), findsOneWidget);
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

      await tester.tap(find.byType(GestureDetector));

      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
      expect(find.byType(OrderInfo), findsOneWidget);

    });
   
  });
}
```

Order page code:

```
ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: productController
                            .orders.value.data!.customer!.orders!.edges!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            key: const ValueKey("OrderInfo"),
                            onTap: () {
                              Get.to(OrderInfo(productController.orders.value
                                  .data!.customer!.orders!.edges![index]));
                            },
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 25,
                                left: 15,
                                right: 15,
                              ),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border.all(
                                      width: 0.5,
                                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 212, 212, 212),
                                    ),
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              top: 10, left: 15, right: 15),
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                            width: 80.0,
                                            height: 80.0,
                                            child: Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                              children: [
                                                if (productController
                                                        .orders
                                                        .value
                                                        .data!
                                                        .customer!
                                                        .orders!
                                                        .edges![index]
                                                        .node!
                                                        .lineItems!
                                                        .edges![0]
                                                        .node1!
                                                        .variant !=
                                                    null)
                                                  if (productController
                                                          .orders
                                                          .value
                                                          .data!
                                                          .customer!
                                                          .orders!
                                                          .edges![index]
                                                          .node!
                                                          .lineItems!
                                                          .edges![0]
                                                          .node1!
                                                          .variant!
                                                          .image !=
                                                      null)
                                                    Container(
                                                      width: 80.0,
                                                      height: 70.0,
                                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                          image: DecorationImage(
                                                              image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                                                  productController
                                                                      .orders
                                                                      .value
                                                                      .data!
                                                                      .customer!
                                                                      .orders!
                                                                      .edges![
                                                                          index]
                                                                      .node!
                                                                      .lineItems!
                                                                      .edges![0]
                                                                      .node1!
                                                                      .variant!
                                                                      .image!
                                                                      .url
                                                                      .toString()),
                                                              fit:
                                                                  BoxFit.cover),
                                                          border: Border.all(
                                                            width: 0.5,
                                                            color: Color(
                                                                0xffe3e3e3),
                                                          ),
                                                          borderRadius:
                                                              BorderRadius.all(
                                                                  Radius
                                                                      .circular(
                                                                          5))),
                                                    )
                                                  else
                                                    Container(
                                                      width: 80.0,
                                                      height: 110.0,
                                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                          border: Border.all(
                                                            width: 0.5,
                                                            color: Color(
                                                                0xffe3e3e3),
                                                          ),
                                                          borderRadius:
                                                              BorderRadius.all(
                                                                  Radius
                                                                      .circular(
                                                                          5))),
                                                      child: Center(
                                                        child: Image.asset(
                                                          'assets/images/logo.png',
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              top: 0, left: 15, right: 15),
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: Get.width / 2,
                                            child: Text(
                                              productController
                                                  .orders
                                                  .value
                                                  .data!
                                                  .customer!
                                                  .orders!
                                                  .edges![index]
                                                  .node!
                                                  .lineItems!
                                                  .edges![0]
                                                  .node1!
                                                  .title
                                                  .toString(),
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                  letterSpacing: 0.2),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          top: 20, left: 15, right: 15),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                              '${'createdon'.tr}: ${productController.orders.value.data!.customer!.orders!.edges![index].node!.displayProcessedAt.toString()}',
                                              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                                  color:
                                                      const Color(0xff6e8498),
                                                  fontSize: 12,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                  letterSpacing: 0.2)),
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                top: 0, left: 0),
                                            child: Container(
                                              width: 100,
                                              child: Text(
                                                  "${"orderno".tr}: ${productController.orders.value.data!.customer!.orders!.edges![index].node!.orderNumber.toString()}",
                                                  overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                                      color: const Color(
                                                          0xff6e8498),
                                                      fontSize: 12,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w500,
                                                      letterSpacing: 0.2)),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          top: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
                                      child: SizedBox(
                                        width: 350.0,
                                        height: 70.0,
                                        child: Card(
                                          color: Color(0xffF0EAFF),
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                top: 8, left: 5),
                                            child: Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                              children: [
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                      const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          top: 5, left: 0),
                                                  child: Column(
                                                    children: [
                                                      Text('totalamount'.tr,
                                                          style: GoogleFonts
                                                              .poppins(
                                                            color: Color(
                                                                0xff6e8498),
                                                            fontSize: 12,
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight.w500,
                                                            letterSpacing: 0.3,
                                                          )),
                                                      Text(
                                                          'BHD${" ${productController.orders.value.data!.customer!.orders!.edges![index].node!.lineItems!.edges![0].node1!.originalTotalPrice!.amount}"}',
                                                          overflow:
                                                              TextOverflow.clip,
                                                          style: GoogleFonts
                                                              .poppins(
                                                            color: Color(
                                                                0xff000000),
                                                            fontSize: 14,
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight.w500,
                                                            letterSpacing: 0.3,
                                                          )),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                ),
}),
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick way to achieve this:

Ex:
List items  -- list of containers wrapped with a gesture detector

item1

item2

item3

Case1:

Lets say you want to tap on item 2 and you know already some text value from item2

```
await tester.tap(find.descendant(find.byType(GestureDetector), find.text("any text on item 2")));
```

Case 2:
If you are not bothered about with any text on list item

```
await tester.tap(find.byType(GestureDetector).first); // tap on first item of the list
await tester.tap(find.byType(GestureDetector).last); // tap on last item of the list
```

Note:

Accordingly you have to handle scrolling on list items to reach last item of the list